# 12.04 upgrade from 11.10 failed, cannot finish upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

After running the upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04, the upgrade manager crashed during the installation portion.

Now, when I run the update manager, it tells me:

```
Not all updates can be installed.
Run a partial upgrade, to install as many updates as possible.
```

However, when I click "Partial Upgrade," I get this error:

```
Failed to run /usr/bin/update-manager '--dist-upgrade' as user root.
Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file.
```

How can I get my upgrade to finish?

I have tried several suggestions I've found on the internet, including `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but always get errors.

Comment: Not sure if this will work or not, so I am putting it in as a comment. Do a do apt-get dist-upgrade in the terminal and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I solve this problem by using terminal instead Upgrade Manager:

1. Update sourcelists. First check you use right sourcelists:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   ***OR***
2. Use diagnostic checker (Update + Diagnostic broken dependecies):

   ```
   sudo apt-get check
   ```

   ***THEN***
3. Upgrade distribution (This is the equivalent of "Mark all upgrades" in Synaptic):

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
4. "Smart upgrade". It tells APT to use "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary. :

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

For other cases read this article:
[***AptGet/Howto: Package management with APT***](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, where the installer was complaining about a printer driver. 
Try removing the Xauthorization file from the `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.
Then run the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command. You can always manually copy the Xauthorization file again after the upgrade.